Ошибка: error: package android.test does not exist import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

error: package android.test does not exist
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

Содержание файла ApplicationTest признано ошибкой. Внутрення помощь Андроид Студио не помогает... (какие-то не адекватные советы-рецепты)
package top.site.name;
import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}

Т.е. по сообщению системы это настройка Теста устарела...
(Ни одно решение на иностранных ресурсах мне не помогло... Я действительно искал решение)

Действительно, ни одно решение на иностранных ресурсах мне не помогло...
Но, вдруг, неожиданно помогло обновление Андроид Студии.
Тест самоисправился, ошибка самоустранилась. Сейчас все норм
